# Is China suffering increased crime levels or reduced GDP growth from having 17% more men than women in the 15-24 age bracket?

Tags: china, demographics, society

It’s often claimed (for example in [What purpose do anti-Polygamy laws serve?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24813/what-purpose-do-anti-polygamy-laws-serve)) that young men who can’t find a woman will instead engage in violence and other types of anti social behavior.

China [currently has](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_by_sex_ratio) 17% more men than women in the 15-24 age bracket due to sex selective abortions being common in their society. Are they suffering any significant downsides as a result? They do have a very low fertility rate but [South Korea’s TFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_and_dependencies_by_total_fertility_rate) is even lower despite not having the same gender imbalance.

Comment: I wonder why Korea does not have the same imbalance - I would have assumed they would.

Comment: 1) Voting to close as off-topic but with edits this might be addressed. 2) Does the "Consequences" section of the Wikipedia articles not answer your question already though? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex-ratio_imbalance_in_China

Comment: @alamar China intentionally tried to make its birth rate be much less than the 2.1 children per woman needed to sustain a country's population with its vigorously enforced one family, old child rule. That law was very unique. (South Korea never had such a law.) Even after retracting that rule, China still has a paucity of children, both male and female, and females more so than males.

Comment: @BrianZ the wiki article seems to say there’s basically no visible consequences

Comment: @alamar  Sex-selective abortions in China were mostly because a couple was allowed to have only one child and most couples wanted it to be a male. Korea didn't have one child policy.

Comment: Are you refering to One-child policy? Or to be more precise its results.

Comment: @JonathanReez 1) I don't think you're reading the same article I linked to if you think it says there are no consequences. It discusses a wide range of them. 2) If the article actually did show that there were no consequences, it would still be a complete to answer your question as currently posed.

Comment: @alamar You might also ask about India, which has 7-8% more males than females.

Comment: @shoover India does have quite a lot of violence/unrest, so the answer would be less clear. China is an interesting case because it seems like they suffer zero consequences.

Comment: @JonathanReez You appear to have read a different wikipedia page than I or Brian Z did. The page to which Brian Z linked details several bad consequences.

Comment: @BrianZ I'm not sure why this is off topic?  It's asking about the result of one policy so as to inform the making of a second policy.  We have allowed topics that asked about facts that would directly inform a policy instead of asking about the policy directly before, even heavily upvoted some, so how would this question be any different?  I admit the question title could be cleaned up to make how the policy is relevant more clear, but the question itself seems applicable.

Comment: @DavidHammen it doesn't look like there's any correlation between gender ratios and violence, which is the biggest claim made by anti-polygamy activists. The rest is pretty vague and might not be correlated to the gender ratio per se.

Comment: @dsollen You don't currently mention any policy in your question, but you could edit based on what you're saying in the commens.

Comment: @BrianZ not my question, but seems OP explicitly said he is asking because it was brought up in regards to a question on the legality of polygamous marriage, legality of marriage seems a policy to me.  OP could potentially add more explicitly that their interested in china is due to the 1 child policy and it's affects, but even without the latter the fact that the question directly relates to a policy of potential marriage legality seems sufficient justification for this site.

Comment: Depends on the circumstances. If it came down to a war, it might prove an advantage; see Wagner. I.e. having lots of disposable men is useful sometimes.

Comment: Not sure what downsides are meant here? Would for example slow population growth be one? Also, what is TFR?

Comment: @Trilarion primarily effects on crime levels, but also other factors that affect GDP growth.

Comment: FWIW [history trends in gender birth ratios for China](https://www.statista.com/statistics/282119/china-sex-ratio-by-age-group/)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, but perhaps not as the ones you discuss.  [The South China Daily Post has an article:](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/article/3133656/china-home-30-million-men-search-bride-census-shows?module=perpetual_scroll_0&pgtype=article&campaign=3133656)

> Cai Yong, an associate professor of social demography at the University of North Carolina, said men from lower social classes faced the most difficulty finding brides.
>
> “They tend to be at the bottom of society and do not have the skills to compete,” he said. “They mostly come from rural areas and are less well educated.”
>
> Jiang [a demography professor at Xian Jiaotong University] said bachelors were also more likely to suffer health problems.
> “Without marriage, these excess males will suffer poorer physical and psychological health,” he said.
>
> “Chinese people rely on their spouses and children for support in old age, but these men have no such relationships.”

Thus the problems will grow, with the government having to step in and provide for millions of unmarried, poor old men in the 2060s and beyond.

But:

> Cai sought to dismiss a widely held assumption that China’s surplus of single men was to blame for social instability and crime.
>
> “The correlation between gender imbalance and crime rate is not strong,” he said.

Comment: "men from lower social classes faced the most difficulty finding brides" This would be true if there were 100 women for every man. Might as well be saying the ugly men struggle. Has nothing to do with a gender population imbalance and the problems it causes.

Comment: @candied_orange It's a situation exhasurbated by lack of potential wives.  More men wanting a wife will fail to get them if there are fewer men.  To a lesser extent it's possible if their culture was aware of the lack of potential brides men who currenty lack wives may have a bleaker outlook and be more resigned to failure then a 20 something in a place with more potential wives who just thinks he hasn't found the right one yet.  In other words more fear and regret may exist about difficulty of having a wife because they know how hard it is.

Comment: @dsollen The phrasing is "most difficulty". As the poorest you face that regardless. Seriously the imbalance would be a problem for all the men. Not just the poorest. Phrasing it this way just makes it seem like it's someone else's problem.

Comment: @candied_orange but it is a problem for the poorest.  They statistically are less likely to get a wife then the richer ones.  That's just statistics not trying to phrase things differently.  If I say that homelessness is more to occur in the poorest demographic am I somehow saying homelessness isn't a problem, or pointing out who most often experiences it.  Suicide is more common in lower socioeconomic brackets.  That doesn't mean rich people can't end up committing suicide.  It doesn't mean that suicide isn't something we want to prevent.  It's just statistics.

Comment: @dsollen it's a problem for them all. It's called scarcity. It effects everyone competing. A wife is not fungible. It matters who you marry. There's a lot more to being married then just if you are or if you aren't.

Comment: @dsollen if only the worst-ranked women were likewise removed from the dating pool, it would indeed only affect the worst-ranked men. But since the removals are ~random, it affects the dating life of everyone.

Comment: Well, the Chinese regime was no problem cutting benefits to the elderly.  https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-64658729 A more likely solution would be a war somewhere to solve this excess male problem.

Comment: Chinese propaganda is already claiming the US is "Ukrainizing"... Australia https://www.nzherald.co.nz/world/us-is-preparing-australia-to-go-to-war-against-china-claims-former-diplomat/TPQAHMDKOJAQ5BTASBWMAXU37E/